# Would you please take a look if my substantiation is correct?

Tags: probability, puzzle

The four numbers 4, 5, 6, 7 are randomly inserted into 7 .3 .4 . 6 . 48

The result is a ten-digit number - for example, 7 4 3 5 4 6 6 7 48

How high is the chance, that the number created is divisible by 36?

Id say it is 100%

36 = 4 • 9 
this means that
the number is exactly divisible by 36, 
if it is at the same time by 4 and 9.

The constructed number is always divisible by 9, 
since the sum of all its digits(54) is divisible by 9.

And it is also divisible by 4, because their last two numbers (48) are divisible by 4.

Comment: all 4 numbers? no thing can be excluded?

Comment: Sounds good, iff you have to insert all 4 numbers exactly once.

Comment: You are 100% correct !

Comment: @jonnytan999 yes, all 4 numbers have to be included

Comment: then, it shld be correct

Comment: you can also show that the number should leave a remainder of 6 when divided by 11